# Openerp Allow Employees to only aceess their own employee directory

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I need an record rule for Allow Employees to only aceess their own employee directory.
So I have used this rule

```
 ['|',('user_id','=',user.id),('user_id','=',False)]
```

It working fine when employee login he can see only his own  employee directory . But the issue is when he tried to create any request  for example  **Leave request** an error occuring

> (self._description, operation))
>   except_orm: (u'Access Denied', u'The
>   requested operation cannot be
>   completed due  to security
>   restrictions. Please contact your
>   system administrator.\n\n(Documen t
>   type: Employee, Operation: read)')
>   2013-11-25 05:55:11,394 6052
>   ←[1;31m←[1;49mERROR←[0m temp
>   openerp.netsvc: Access  Denied The
>   requested operation cannot be
>   completed due to security
>   restrictions. Please  contact your
>   system administrator.

When remove the record rule everything works fine , what is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Write an Record Rule for that. Check in Settings--> Security --> Record Rules

Comment: Yes I  wrote a record rule for that ,but there is an issue in it. I have specified it in my question

Comment: It's because when making a leave request, system need to read the data of Manager of that employee, for which system does not have any rights.